# GETH node in snap syncmode transaction receipts are missing until block ~5265000

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm running GETH in syncmode=snap with the latest image ethereum/client-go:latest.
Parameters: --http --http.port=8545 --http.addr=0.0.0.0 --http.vhosts="*" --http.api=eth,debug,net,txpool --authrpc.jwtsecret=/tmp/jwt_token/jwt.hex --authrpc.vhosts="*" --authrpc.addr=0.0.0.0 --syncmode snap --vmodule="rpc=1"

Expected to have receipts for all transactions that have a receipt, however there missing receipts up to block number ~5267000.
For instance the trx from block 5265000 doesn't show any receipt:

> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x45485d3edd212b9ed015e7ffa6a29b6b4af4894a9eed4f46a22435b6821a7ea7")
> null

In GETH with syncmode=full the same trx returns with the corrects receipt:

> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x45485d3edd212b9ed015e7ffa6a29b6b4af4894a9eed4f46a22435b6821a7ea7")
> {
> blockHash: "0xf9e5daac44acce810b25aff6ca20d9e554ef7ed5df15179d7e9929f4a4006198",
> blockNumber: 5265000,
> contractAddress: null,
> cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
> effectiveGasPrice: 130000000000,
> from: "0x3974d816a969908a82428384c728fbd8faffbfe1",
> gasUsed: 21000,
> logs: [],
> logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
> status: "0x1",
> to: "0xca01c168dd2bfe59bf8ae6f3ac0cfea6a0cbf420",
> transactionHash: "0x45485d3edd212b9ed015e7ffa6a29b6b4af4894a9eed4f46a22435b6821a7ea7",
> transactionIndex: 0,
> type: "0x0"
> }

The chain is still syncing:
INFO [11-09|09:20:10.061] Syncing: chain download in progress      synced=90.86% chain=445.58GiB  headers=16,875,466@7.62GiB   bodies=16,839,764@300.05GiB receipts=16,839,764@137.91GiB eta=9h8m38.990s

Have I wait the chain to fully sync?
Did I miss anything?